# Passing a class pointer as a function argument

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+

Currently I am trying to create a function to implement modularization in the code like below.

[Code 1]

```
float CBitmapWaterMark::DrawPrintInfoText(HDC hDC)
{
    StringFormat* stringFormat = new StringFormat();   
    // I'm trying to pass a stringFormat object to a member function of a class(CBitmapWaterMark). 
    stringFormat->SetAlignment(StringAlignmentNear);
    stringFormat->SetLineAlignment(StringAlignmentNear);
 

    TestFunction(stringFormat) //help point 1
}

VOID CBitmapWaterMark::TestFunction(StringFormat* stringFormat) // help point 2
{
    // implement 
}
```

=> Syntax Error identifier StringFormat

But I don't know how to pass it as a function argument and how to receive it.

---

There seems to be a problem with `StringFormat` which is declared in `<gdiplusstringformat.h>`.

This is a minimal complete reproducible example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <gdiplusstringformat.h>

StringFormat fmt;
```

Error log:

```
1>C:\Project3 C++\main.cpp(5,17): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Project3 C++\main.cpp(5,14): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'fmt'
```

Comment: Your code is not extraordinarily different. Where is StringFormat defined and did you include the necessary header?

Comment: @bot `StringFormat` need not be defined. The compiler is complaining about the fact, that it isn't declared.

Comment: Your code looks fine, but the class (or struct?) `StringFormat` isn't declared, possibly because you forgot to include the header that declares it.

Comment: That's possibly `Gdiplus::StringFormat`. You have to give some clue to the compiler, or to us.

Comment: It is Gdiplus::StringFormat and includes header files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a `using Gdiplus::StringFormat`. The name "StringFormat" is fairly generic, so C++ has *namespaces* to prevent name collisions between 2 libraries. GDI+ puts its names in `namespace Gdiplus`.

Comment: I think it should be just `using Gdiplus;` instead of `using Gdiplus::StringFormat;`. Or use `Gdiplus::StringFormat` instead of `StringFormat`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: If anything, it would be `using namespace Gdiplus`. But just like `using namespace std`, that's a rather imprecise approach.

Comment: Yes, of course `using namespace Gdiplus;`, that was a typo. But my comment is rather pointless anyway, I'll delete it including this this one. UV was mine.

Comment: Thank you so much it has been resolved!!